# Mahalanobis distance to find out nearest neighbor

Tags: matlab, for-loop, distance, distributed, mahalanobis

Suppose I have some original data in a matrix `a` and measured data in matrix `b`. now i want to find out nearest point to matrix `a` 's element from matrix `b.`

The output should be `ans = [1; 2; 3; 4;]`.

But when I try to do it, it does not give an output but error as a and b need to have same number of columns. How to solve this problem?

```
a = [1; 2; 3; 4];
b = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6; 4 5 6 7];
k=1 ;
L = pdist2(a,b,'mahalanobis','smallest',K);
```

Comment: mmm... make them have the same number of columns?

Comment: if a add additional colums using zeros than answer is NaN

Comment: Perhaps `a` should be a row vector. From the documentation: `Rows of X and Y correspond to observations, columns correspond to variables.`